# check password strength in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, passwords

This is the code:

```
export class AppComponent {
   title = 'password-strength-angular';

   public account = {
      password: <string>null
   };
   public barLabel: string = "Password strength:";
   public myColors = ['#DD2C00', '#FF6D00', '#FFD600'];
   public thresholds = [90, 75, 45, 25];
}
```

I get error: *Conversion of type 'null' to type 'string' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.ts(2352)*

Comment: why dont you just set it empty string  ''. password is of type string so default value will be empty string right.

Comment: i was installed package https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng9-password-strength-bar

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
validateData(field:any) {
    switch (field) {
      case 'userName':
        if (this.user.userName == '')
          this.errorMessages.userName =
            "le nom d'utilisateur ne peut pas être vide";
        else this.errorMessages.userName = '';
        break;
      case 'password':
        if (this.user.password == '')
          this.errorMessages.password =
            'le mot de passe ne peut pas être vide';
          else if(! this.user.password.match( /[0-9]/g)){
            this.errorMessages.password =
            'mot de passe doit contenir au minimum un chiffre';
          }
          else if(! this.user.password.match( /[a-z]/g)){
            this.errorMessages.password =
            'mot de passe doit contenir au minimum une lettre minuscule';
          }
          else if(! this.user.password.match( /[A-Z]/g)){
            this.errorMessages.password =
            'mot de passe doit contenir au minimum une lettre majuscule';
          }
          else if(! (this.user.password.length >= 10)){
            this.errorMessages.password =
            'mot de passe doit contenir au minimum 10 caractères';
          }
        else this.errorMessages.password = '';
        break;
      default:
    }
  }
```